# JavaScript ошибка при импорте

Tags: javascript, html

Есть html файл и связанный с ним js файл, при импорте библиотеки возникает ошибка: "SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 'swal'. import call expects one or two arguments."
Подскажите пожайлуйста, что я не правильно делаю. Спасибо.

login.html

```
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Login and Registration</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./styles/styles.css">
    </head>
    
    <body>
    <div class="container">
    
        <div id="test"></div>
    
        <h2>Login</h2>
        <form id="login-form">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="login-username">Username:</label>
                <input type="text" id="login-username" name="username" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="login-password">Password:</label>
                <input type="password" id="login-password" name="password" required>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="login-button">Login</button>
        </form>
        <hr>
        <h2>Register</h2>
        <form id="register-form">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="register-username">Username:</label>
                <input type="text" id="register-username" name="username" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="register-password">Password:</label>
                <input type="password" id="register-password" name="password" required>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="register-button">Register</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    
    <script src="main.js"></script>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

main.js

```
import swal from "sweetalert";
document.getElementById("login-form").addEventListener("submit", async function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const username = document.getElementById("login-username").value;
    const password = document.getElementById("login-password").value;

    // Make an AJAX request (or use the Fetch API) to the server for login
    const response = await fetch('http://localhost:4000/graphql', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            query: `
                mutation {
                    login(username: "${username}", password: "${password}")
                }
            `,
        }),
    });

    const data = await response.json();
    alert(data.data.login);
    console.log(data.data.login)
});

document.getElementById("register-form").addEventListener("submit", async function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const username = document.getElementById("register-username").value;
    const password = document.getElementById("register-password").value;

    // Make an AJAX request (or use the Fetch API) to the server for registration
    const response = await fetch('http://localhost:4000/graphql', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            query: `
                mutation {
                    register(username: "${username}", password: "${password}")
                }
            `,
        }),
    });

    const data = await response.json();
    console.log(data);
    swal(data.data.register, "success")
    alert(data.data.register);


    const example = document.getElementById('test')
    example.innerHTML = data.data.register;

});
```

Comment: Вместо строки `swal(data.data.register, "success")` попробуйте это `swal({title: data.data.register, type: "success", showConfirmButton: false, timer: 1000})`

Comment: Ошибка отображается еще на этапе загрузки HTML файла: https://prnt.sc/7PEgmz20sUM0

Comment: https://doka.guide/js/modules/#osobennosti-v-brauzere

Comment: Странно, добавил type="module", теперь такая ошибка: "TypeError: Module name, 'sweetalert' does not resolve to a valid URL."

Comment: Ничего странного. Читать документацию дальше и не забывать что браузер это совсем не nodejs. Вообще.